# Is there an API that can directly handle the files I need to sign

Tags: docusignapi

Is there an API that can directly handle the files I need to sign.
For example, I set the location and name I need to sign on a document, and then call an API to return to the document that I have signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocuSign eSignature API doesn't support robo-signing.

If you need to automatically apply signatures to files automatically, you'll want to look in to the DocuSign Signature Appliance: https://www.docusign.com/products/hybrid-cloud-appliances

Comment: Is the user's signature behavior only supported on the DocuSign website?